# Imageview And/OR Sound having memory Issue (going in back ground)

Tags: memory-management, ios6, uiimageview, core-animation, automatic-ref-counting

My Application is in ARC.
In any view of my application there is one back ground image and on that image some animations are continuously repeating the images.

**Problem is : My application is going in background after some time.**

I seen and tried Lots of thing on stack, google and on apple doc but didn't got satisfactory solution.
**I have Three Question.**
(1) How to Stop this ?
(2) Is there any other method to release the memory manually in ARC.
(3) If i use [self.view removeFromSuperview]; for UIView then also some memory didn't released in ARC ?

MyCode for Animation is

```
    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy08" ofType:@"png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgBubbleAnimation];

    imageview.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy01" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy02" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy03" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy04" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy05" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy06" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bluecandy07" ofType:@"png"]],
                                          nil];
    [imageview setAnimationRepeatCount:0]; // 0 for continuous
    imageview.animationDuration =3.0;
    [imageview startAnimating];
```

And Sound files are (played when particular button clicked)

```
URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"ect1a" ofType:@"mp3"]];
audioSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL error:nil];
audioSound.delegate = self;
audioSound.volume = 5.0;
audioSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioSound play];
```

I have 15 small sound files for one view and 15 animations for one view.
In every particular Animation there are min 15 images.
Any help, suggestion, link or tutorial are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not using imageview.animationImages is the first thing you need to do to get your memory usage under control. That API should never be used as it lets you shoot yourself in the foot easily. See [imageview-animation-getting-more-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183898/imageview-animation-getting-more-memory/17227721#17227721) or [unpredictable-crash-due-to-uiview-animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316303/unpredictable-crash-due-to-uiview-animations/14316400#comment24955525_14316400) or [iphone-app-memory-leak-with-uiimage-animation-problem-testing-on-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992855/iphone-app-memory-leak-with-uiimage-animation-problem-testing-on-device/17224968#17224968).