# ImageView Animation getting more Memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios6, uiimageview, nsarray

My application is in ARC.
I am using image Animation in imageView but after some period of time my application crashed with low memory error.

I am not getting any error message in Log but in **Profile tool** i am getting **"Low Memory"** message in **allocation** Part.

One code of my Animation is

```
ImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:ImageView];
ImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 342);
ImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image1" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image2" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image3" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image4" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image5" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image6" ofType:@"png"]],
                                  nil];
[ImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
ImageView.animationDuration =1.0;
[ImageView startAnimating];
```

If i comment this animation code then application is running correctly but i need more than 5 this type of animation in one view.

Any Link, tutorial, any Idea will be great help...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with a sprite? I've tried to animate with CALater (Core Animation Layer) and it works like a charm. I animate the 'contentsRect'. Short code example (CALayer subclass):

```
self.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite-large.png"].CGImage;

NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray array]; // array of CGRect's
CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contentsRect"];
anim.values = frames;
[self addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

I've posted some code to GitHub a few weeks ago:
https://github.com/Gerharbo/sprite-animation-layer/

It provides an example sprite (not perfect, but it works) and some example code.

Have fun animating!

Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

Gerharbo's method is basically a texture atlas but with one much bigger image. What I think you will find is that this kind of approach does not scale well when you try to use many images (for a long animation). You are already seeing crashes caused by running out of memory, so it would be a good idea to completely avoid UIImageView.animationImages. This blog post [video-and-memory-usage-on-ios-devices](http://iosgraphicsanimation.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/video-and-memory-usage-on-ios-devices/) describes why you cannot allocate memory to hold a bunch of images in main memory, which is exactly what you code above is trying to do. If you look around on SO you will find many other developers have [ran into this same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617910/loading-images-for-animation-in-uiimageview-ios/17225223#17225223).